# how to convert a json array into javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

the server response data is:
{virus: "[["0家":1907],["1~3家":618],["4~10家":436],["11~20家":1046],["20家以上":924]]"};
then I get this object value by key virus

how to convert this value to javascript array

var value = '"[["0家":1907],["1~3家":618],["4~10家":436],["11~20家":1046],["20家以上":924]]"';

Comment: `var value = jsondatawhatevername.virus` ?

Comment: [Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the string.

Comment: the server response data is a json object {virus: "[["0家":1907],["1~3家":618],["4~10家":436],["11~20家":1046],["20家以上":924]]"} ,I want to convert it value to a javascript array,how to do?

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ltvhkqb/2/  is this you wanted?

Comment: that is what I wanted, but is not the common solution, I want to change the server data

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse();` to convert the XHR response to a JavaScript array.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I have try to use JSON.parse() to convert it, but I get an error 
'SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'

Comment: You need to use valid JSON, there are JSON validators online.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, :

```
var response =  your data;
var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
alert(obj. virus); //true
alert(obj.count);
```

Comment: that's right, thank you!
I can't convert it because my response data is not valid JSON Object